# How to store encrypted credentials for Acumatica Import Scenarios in Github

Tags: acumatica, erp

My team is in the process of migrating from another CRM system to Acumatica. We have several Microsoft SQL Server tables that we are trying to import into Acumatica using a number of Import Scenarios. Currently, we are reusing the same Data Provider for all of the Import Scenarios.

I notice that the database credentials (username, password, etc.) are currently duplicated, in plain text, across each of the Import Scenario XML files in our customization project. We want to avoid committing these credentials to our repo on Github.

One possibility we've considered is to have a single "config" file with the credentials, add it to gitignore, then commit an encrypted version to the repo. Is there a way to do this?

Is there another convenient way to encrypt credentials in Import Scenarios?

Comment: Have you considered using trusted (integrated) security instead of username/password to access SQL?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be possible, since the Data Provider requires you to enter a username and password, regardless of whether you choose SQL or Windows authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have your Acumatica partner create a support case with this info and screen shot to see if this can be considered. I am not sure why system is still requiring user name password if authentication is set to integrated windows.   Perhaps you can also investigate if this validation can be overridden with a customization of the provider.

[image: screenshot of restriction]